# Force flushing of output to a file while bash script is still running

Tags: bash, file, flush

I have a small script, which is called daily by crontab using the following command:

```
/homedir/MyScript &> some_log.log
```

The problem with this method is that some_log.log is only created after MyScript finishes. I would like to flush the output of the program into the file while it's running so I could do things like

```
tail -f some_log.log
```

and keep track of the progress, etc.

Comment: We'll need to have a description -or if possible code- of what your small script does exactly...

Comment: To unbuffer python scripts you could use "python -u". To unbuffer perl scripts, see Greg Hewgill reply below. And so on...

Comment: If you can edit the script, you can usually flush the output buffer explicitly within a script, for example in python with `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

bash itself will never actually write any output to your log file.  Instead, the commands it invokes as part of the script will each individually write output and flush whenever they feel like it.  So your question is really how to force the commands within the bash script to flush, and that depends on what they are.

Comment: I really do not understand this answer.

Comment: For a better idea why standard output behaves like this, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/13933741/282728. A short version—by default, if redirected to a file, stdout is fully buffered; it's written to a file only after a flush. Stderr is not—it's written after every '\n'. One solution is to use the 'script' command recommended by user3258569 below, to have stdout flushed after every line end.

Comment: Stating the obvious, and ten years later, but this is a comment, not an answer, and it shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: This additionally is not accurate answer. The stdout CAN STILL BE behind stderr EVEN if the stdout commands BEFORE the stderr commands. So it is not related to `depends on what they are` because they already depends on something else outside the bash and the bash script itself.

Answer (score 121):

I found a solution to this [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation). Using the OP's example you basically run

```
stdbuf -oL /homedir/MyScript &> some_log.log
```

and then the buffer gets flushed after each line of output. I often combine this with `nohup` to run long jobs on a remote machine.

```
stdbuf -oL nohup /homedir/MyScript &> some_log.log
```

This way your process doesn't get cancelled when you log out.

Comment: Could you add a link to some documentation for `stdbuf`? Based on [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/bash-how-to-flush-output-to-a-file-while-running?answertab=votes#comment4951700_4520994) it seems like it's not available on some distros. Could you clarify?

Comment: stdbuf -o adjusts stdout buffering. The other options are -i and -e for stdin and stderr. L sets line buffering. One could also specify buffer size, or 0 for no buffering.

Comment: that link is no longer available.

Comment: @NicHartley: `stdbuf` is part of GNU coreutils, [documentation can be found at gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation)

Comment: In case it helps anyone, [use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348559/ddg#35348702) `export -f my_function` and then `stdbuf -oL bash -c "my_function -args"` if you need to run a function instead of a script

Comment: Didn't work for me on GitHub Actions. For something as simple as `apk add coreutils && stdbuf -o0 -e0 -i0 sh -xc 'set && whoami && pwd && ls && exit 1'`. With [`unbuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337310/52499) it works.

Comment: Did not work for me Ubuntu 20, inside tmux at least

Answer (score 45):

```
script -c <PROGRAM> -f OUTPUT.txt
```

Key is -f. Quote from man script:

```
-f, --flush
     Flush output after each write.  This is nice for telecooperation: one person
     does 'mkfifo foo; script -f foo', and another can supervise real-time what is
     being done using 'cat foo'.
```

Run in background:

```
nohup script -c <PROGRAM> -f OUTPUT.txt
```

Comment: Wow! A solution that works in `busybox`! (my shell freezes afterwards, but whatever)

Comment: what is `-c` for?

Comment: From `man script`: `-c`, `--command command` Run the command rather than an interactive shell.  This makes it easy for a script to capture the output of a program that behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty. Another useful argument is `-q` and can be combined with `-c` like this: `-qc`. This prevents start and done messages to the standard output.

Comment: I note on BSD unix it is `-F` (capital f) for some reason... the `-f` option does something completely different.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `tee` to write to the file without the need for flushing.

```
/homedir/MyScript 2>&1 | tee some_log.log > /dev/null
```

Comment: This still buffers the output, at least in my Ubuntu 18.04 environment.  The contents eventually get written to the file either way, but I think the OP is asking for a method where they can monitor the progress more accurately before the file is finished writing, and this method doesn't allow for that any more than output redirection does.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a function of `bash`, as all the shell does is open the file in question and then pass the file descriptor as the standard output of the script. What you need to do is make sure output is flushed *from your script* more frequently than you currently are.

In Perl for example, this could be accomplished by setting:

```
$| = 1;
```

See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more information on this.

Comment: not really an answer if you don't have access to modify the script.

Answer (score 6):

Would this help?

```
tail -f access.log | stdbuf -oL cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq
```

This will immediately display unique entries from access.log using the [stdbuf utility](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/stdbuf-man.html).

Comment: The only trouble is that stdbuf seems to be some old utility which is not available on new distros.

Comment: ..nor in my busybox :(

Comment: Actually I have `stdbuf` available in Ubuntu at the moment, not sure where I got it.

Comment: I have stdbuf in Centos 7.5

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, `stdbuf` is part of `coreutilus` (found with `apt-file search /usr/bin/stdbuf`).

Answer (score 3):

Buffering of output depends on how your program `/homedir/MyScript` is implemented. If you find that output is getting buffered, you have to force it in your implementation. For example, use sys.stdout.flush() if it's a python program or use fflush(stdout) if it's a C program.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks `@user3258569`, script is maybe the only thing that works in `busybox`!

The shell was freezing for me after it, though. Looking for the cause, I found these big red warnings "don't use in a non-interactive shells" in [script manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html#BUGS):

> `script` is primarily designed for interactive terminal sessions.  When
>          stdin is not a terminal (for example: `echo foo | script`), then the
>          session can hang, because the interactive shell within the script
>          session misses **EOF** and `script` has no clue when to close the session.
>          See the **NOTES** section for more information.

True. `script -c "make_hay" -f /dev/null | grep "needle"` was freezing the shell for me.

Countrary to the warning, I thought that `echo "make_hay" | script` WILL pass a EOF, so I tried

```
echo "make_hay; exit" | script -f /dev/null | grep 'needle'
```

and it worked!

Note the warnings in the man page. This may not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

How just spotted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429973/3569208) the problem is that you have to wait that the programs that you run from your script finish their jobs.
If in your script you run program in **background** you can try something more.

In general a call to `sync` before you exit allows to flush file system buffers and can help a little.

If in the script you start some programs in **background** (`&`), you can [**wait**](http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html) that they finish before you exit from the script. To have an idea about how it can function you can see below

```
#!/bin/bash
#... some stuffs ...
program_1 &          # here you start a program 1 in background
PID_PROGRAM_1=${!}   # here you remember its PID
#... some other stuffs ... 
program_2 &          # here you start a program 2 in background
wait ${!}            # You wait it finish not really useful here
#... some other stuffs ... 
daemon_1 &           # We will not wait it will finish
program_3 &          # here you start a program 1 in background
PID_PROGRAM_3=${!}   # here you remember its PID
#... last other stuffs ... 
sync
wait $PID_PROGRAM_1
wait $PID_PROGRAM_3  # program 2 is just ended
# ...
```

Since `wait` works with jobs as well as with `PID` numbers a lazy solution should be to put at the end of the script

```
for job in `jobs -p`
do
   wait $job 
done
```

More difficult is the situation if you run something that run something else in background because you have to search and wait (if it is the case) the end of all the **child** process: for example if you run a **daemon** probably it is not the case to wait it finishes :-).

Note:

- wait ${!} means "wait till the last background process is completed" where `$!` is the PID of the last background process. So to put `wait ${!}` just after `program_2 &` is equivalent to execute directly `program_2` without sending it in background with `&`
- From the help of [`wait`](http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html):

  ```
  Syntax    
      wait [n ...]
  Key  
      n A process ID or a job specification
  ```

Answer (score 0):

alternative to stdbuf is `awk '{print} END {fflush()}'`
I wish there were a bash builtin to do this.
Normally it shouldn't be necessary, but with older versions there might be bash synchronization bugs on file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where a redirect was sometimes buffering.

I couldnt easily use stdbuf cos my command was a bash function.
You had to export the function in this case which was too much work.

My workaround was touching the file prior to it being used.

eg.

```
mybashfunction >> ${mybufferedfile}
touch ${mybufferedfile}  <--- I needed to add this
diff mybufferedfile identical.output.txt
```

Without the touch command, the file was buffered, sometimes.
And the diff found differences cos of the incomplete buffered file.

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem with a background process in Mac OS X using the `StartupItems`. This is how I solve it:

If I make `sudo ps aux` I can see that `mytool` is launched.

I found that (due to buffering) when Mac OS X shuts down `mytool` never transfers the output to the `sed` command. However, if I execute `sudo killall mytool`, then `mytool` transfers the output to the `sed` command. Hence, I added a `stop` case to the `StartupItems` that is executed when Mac OS X shuts down:

```
start)
    if [ -x /sw/sbin/mytool ]; then
      # run the daemon
      ConsoleMessage "Starting mytool"
      (mytool | sed .... >> myfile.txt) & 
    fi
    ;;
stop)
    ConsoleMessage "Killing mytool"
    killall mytool
    ;;
```

Comment: This really is not a good answer Freeman since it is very specific to your environment.  The OP wants to monitor output not kill it.

Answer (score -4):

well like it or not this is how redirection works.

In your case the output (meaning your script has finished) of your script redirected to that file.

What you want to do is add those redirections in your script.

Answer (score -5):

I don't know if it would work, but what about calling `sync`?

Comment: `sync` is a low-level filesystem operation and is unrelated to buffered output at the application level.

Comment: `sync` writes any dirty filesystem buffers to physical storage, if necessary. This is internal to the OS; applications running on top of the OS always see a coherent view of the filesystem whether or not the disk blocks have been written to physical storage. For the original question, the application (script) is probably buffering the output in a buffer internal to the application, and the OS won't even know (yet) that the output is actually destined to be written to stdout. So a hypothetical "sync"-type operation wouldn't be able to "reach into" the script and pull the data out.