# how to show program output on screen and also put them into a log file on linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to show program output on screen and also put them into a log file on linux
I tried:

```
    <program> 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

or

```
    <program> |& tee logfile
```

indeed, they can do what I want 
but the output is not shown on screen and I can't see  anything when `vim` the logfile
until the program finishes

how to deal with this problem?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force line-buffering of stdout when piping to tee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee)

Answer (score 0):

You can run that command:

```
script -f -c "program" logfile
```

This will launch your program and logs both its standard output and error streams to logfile in an unbuffered manner.

One drawback will be stdin will also present in the output (unless un-echoed on screen) but that might be a useful feature.