# Apache ErrorLog write log and execute Python script

Tags: python, apache, graylog2

I'm trying to write Apache 2.4 errors to an error log and sending them to a Graylog2 server using a Python script. Looking at examples such as http://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/apache/syslog_logs_notes.html and http://zindilis.com/docs/apache-logs-to-remote-syslog.html. The examples show I should use tee, for example:

`ErrorLog "| tee -a /var/log/httpd/error_log | nc -u -j syslog.example.com 514"`

I'm doing the following:

`ErrorLog "| /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/domains/test.error.log | /usr/bin/python /opt/apache2gelf/test.py"`

The messages are written to the logs but the python script is not executed. The Python script has 755 permissions. What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks good. How do you verify Python script is not executed?

Comment: Sounds like something to do with `tee`'s buffer, have seen this myself using it in the past. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee

Comment: @Mikko I'm writing something to a file to test it.

Comment: @arco do you have an example how I could do it?

Comment: Try without tee for a test?

Comment: ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/python /opt/apache2gelf/test.py" works fine. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ErrorLog "| /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/domains/test.error.log | xargs /opt/apache2gelf/test.py"
```

And make sure that the first line of your script is a proper interpreter, e.g ***#!/usr/bin/env python***

Comment: Only the error log is written, the python script does not write to the test file. The first line of the Python script is #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: I've updated the command in the answer "| xargs /opt/apache2gelf/test.py", try it.

Comment: Unfortunately I get exactly the same result as before.