# Better way to output to both console and output file than tee?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

What I need to display is a log refreshing periodically. It's a block of about 10 lines of text. I'm using `|tee` and it works right now. However, the performance is less satisfying. It waits a while and then outputs several blocks of texts from multiple refreshes (especially when the program just starts, it takes quite a while to start displaying anything on the console and the first time I saw this, I thought the program was hanging). In addition, it breaks randomly in the middle of the last block, so it's quite ugly to present.

Is there a way to improve this? (Maybe output less each time and switch between output file and console more frequently?)

Comment: Note that there's a pretty good chance this question would really work better on [SU]. Still, it's not exactly off-topic here, so don't worry too much just yet.

Comment: I doubt there's much you can do apart from modifying the program that produces the output: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin), for example.

Comment: Please clarify how `tee` receives its input here, i.e., how log changes are being detected and output.

Comment: Sounds like STDOUT buffering is causing issues.  [Check this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11337041/477563) for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by flushing stdout after printing each block. Credit to Kenneth L!
https://superuser.com/questions/889019/bash-better-way-to-output-to-both-console-and-output-file-than-tee

Comment: Generally, if you solved your own problem, mark your _own_ answer as accepted, so future readers know what worked.
However, please provide more detail on how you solved the problem; there's no "Kenneth L" mentioned on this page (users sometimes change their names).
I assume it was one of the _comments_ that provided the crucial clue, but note that people restricted themselves to quick comments, because you didn't provide enough detail in your _question_, either (who's producing the output, and how? a file being appended to? a program you control? ...).

Comment: Please note that StackExchange doesn't allow you to accept your own answer until one day later and forgive me that I didn't set an alarm and actively countdown 24 hours to mark this question as answered.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to accept your answer (I'd forgotten about the 24-hour rule) and for providing more detail. Since it's still only _implied_, let me state it explicitly: Your log source is a program _you_ control and you were able to modify it to flush the stdout buffer as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can monitor the log *as a file* directly [*update*: turned out not to be the case]:

The usual way of monitoring a [log] file for new lines is to use `tail -f`, which - from what I can tell - prints new data added to the log file *as it is being added*, without buffering.

Similarly, `tee` passes data it receives via stdin on without buffering.

Thus, you should be able to combine the two:

```
 tail -f logFile | tee newLogEntriesFile
```