# tee doesn't write to screen or file

Tags: linux, tee

I use the following command to see which VirtualHosts are getting traffic on my server (alternatives welcome).

```
 ngrep 'Host:' port 80 -t  -W byline -q | grep  '^Host'
```

I want to be able to analyse the number of hits in a time interval while also seeing what's going on. To do this I have been trying to write the output to a file while also displaying it using tee.

```
 ngrep 'Host:' port 80 -t  -W byline -q | grep  '^Host' | tee ~/hosts.log
```

However, nothing is printed to screen or logged to file.

I have tried different file locations, outside of my `screen` session - with no difference. Does `grep` need special handling?

Comment: Check which `tee` you are using with `which tee`.  Make sure it's actually the `tee` command and not something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force line-buffering of stdout when piping to tee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is line buffering at play on the part of both `ngrep` and `grep`. Here is how you can get aroundthe issue you’re seeing:

```
% sudo ngrep 'Host:' port 80 -t -W byline -d lo -q -l |grep --line-buffered '^Host:' |tee foo.log
```

Notice that `ngrep` is using `-l` to make *stdout* line buffered, and `grep` uses `--line-buffered` for the same.

(I added the `-d lo` just for my own testing.)

Answer (score 3):

You might use the [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) command, like this:

```
ngrep 'Host:' port 80 -t  -W byline -q | stdbuf -o0 grep '^Host' | tee /tmp/hosts
```

I'm setting the `stdout` buffer of `grep` to zero.

`stdbuf` is a general hammer that works for programs which are linked against `glibc` since output/input buffering happens in the libc. The ouput of a program which is writing to a terminal will getting line buffered, the output of a program which is outputting to a pipe or a file will getting block buffered - unless the program itself calls `flush()`. You can use `stdbuf` to modify this behaviour.

Btw, `ngrep` and `tee` seem to call `flush()` (`ngrep` on stdout, `tee` on stdin) since we didn't needed to use `stdbuf` for them.

---

I would accept [MicahElliot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31840084/171318) since `--line-buffered` is more specific for `grep` and should be used here. `stdbuf` is a nice alternative for programs which does not offer such an option (and for guys like me which didn't read grep's man page before ;) )

Comment: Thanks for recommending which to accept :) I used yours because I'm lazy and it was less typing; I need to go read the man pages for @Micah Elliott's answer to understand the flags!

Comment: @PeterB Btw, MANY THANKS for showing me that nice tool!! I didn't know about `ngrep` before. Cool! A little search gave me also `netsed` - which sounds also promising!