# interrupt linux command redirection can loss data?

Tags: c, linux, bash

If I run such a bash script, and in the script, it will invoke some executable command, such as the following

```
myexec args1 arg2 > out.txt
```

myexec will print some log info through the c API printf. If I interrupt the script, because myexec is stuck by some unknown reason, does some log information will be lost, and not save to the out.txt file? In my experiment, I found it is, but is there any way to solve this? and I do not know why the log information not flush to the out.txt file

========

I use the stdbuf solved my problem, the related question is: [Force line-buffering of stdout when piping to tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee)

Comment: Pretty much depends on a lot of things like buffer size, flush frequency, way printf is accessed, and most importantly your program, show the code.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have no source code. I really want to know if whether I can have method to capture the log when I interrupt it.  Such as I wrap the above code in the python fabric command. when I interrupt the execution, there is a exception, and I use a try...finally flush all the log info to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you interrupt the script, there's a good chance the `stdout` buffer isn't flushed.  In your program, immediately after every `printf`, add an `fflush(stdout)` to flush the buffer. Alternatively, add a newline character (`\n`) at the end of your `printf` - that flushes the buffer too (but adds a newline to your log output).

Comment: Thanks! I will use this in my program later. But I can not modify this executable  now, because I can not modify the source code, I only know that it will log some information.

Comment: In that case - try the answer to this question, which is a bit more similar to your current predicament: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee

Comment: Newlines won't flush the buffer if stdout is redirected to a file. That'll switch to block buffering by default.

Comment: @tonysdg thanks, from you given url, I find the method stdbuf works, how amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify signal that will correctly finish your program (*`SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2`* etc, though you can't override `SIGKILL`). In signal handler flush your output stream (`fflush(stdout)` or alternatives) and shutdown app.
To stop your programm type smth like

> kill -SIGUSR1 `pidof myapp`

Comment: This is definitely the more elegant way of handling the problem.  A bit more complicated too.

Comment: In my server apps I write logs with fprintf(stdout,...) with overriding stdout and without any flushes. This make program run faster without removing logs. If I do need to read full logs - i use overrided SIGUSR1 that just flushes stdout.

Comment: Thanks very much ! Good point,  but also only apply to you have the source code.