# how to redirect the std out immediately to a file in C++ or python?

Tags: python, c++, stdout

In c++, I have this code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<<"before-sleep"<<endl;
  sleep(5);
  cout<<"after-sleep"<<endl;
  return 1;
}
```

then i compile it with g++ to main.exe and run it. when run it I redirect the std out to a file :

```
./main.exe > file.log
```

however, the two line "before-sleep" and "after-sleep" are print to the file almost at the same time -- all have 5s delay. How can I made the first line print to the file immediately and the second line print to the file with 5s delay?

The situation is the same in python:

```
import time
print 'before sleep'
time.sleep(5)
print 'after sleep'
```

Comment: try `cout.flush();` just before `sleep(5);`

Comment: This is entirely a buffering issue. Note that `endl` flushes the buffer in c++, so I suspect the problem is buffering in the shell redirection. Might want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee). For Python, you'll need to add an `sys.stdout.flush()` after the first print.

Comment: @Logman `endl` is special: it both outputs out a newline and flushes.

Comment: @Alec endl should flush buffer but in my experience on some systems I encountered it doesn't.

Comment: both the cout.flush() and sys.stdout.fush() doesn't work respectvely in c++ and python,  does it works in your computer ?@Alec  @Logman

Comment: Yes it works on my computer. As Alec said it probably something with IO buffers or your test has error. Try using `tail -f file.log` to confirmed your test is valid.