# bash can't capture output from aria2c to variable and stdout

Tags: bash, variables, stdout, capture, aria2

I am trying to use aria2c to download a file. The command looks like this:

```
aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath
```

The command works perfectly from the script when run this way.  What I'm trying to do is capture the output from the command to a variable and still display it on the screen in real-time.

I have successfully captured the output to a variable by using:

```
VAR=$(aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath)
```

With this scenario though, there's a long delay on the screen where there's no update while the download is happening. I have an echo command after this line in the script and $VAR has all of the aria2c download data captured.

I have tried using different combinations of 2>&1, and | tee /dev/tty at the end of the command, but nothing shows in the display  in realtime.

```
Example:
VAR=$(aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath 2>&1)
VAR=$(aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty )
VAR=$(aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath | tee /dev/tty )
VAR=$((aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath) 2>&1)
VAR=$((aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath) 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty )
VAR=$((aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath) 2>&1 ) | tee /dev/tty )
```

I've been able to use the "2>&1 | tee" combination before with other commands but for some reason I can't seem to capture aria2c to both simultaneously.  Anyone had any luck doing this from a bash script?

Comment: Seems like a buffering problem.  Check this post: [Force line-buffering of stdout when piping to tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee).

Answer (score 1):

Since aria2c seems to output to stdout, consider `tee`ing that to stderr:

```
var=$(aria2c --http-user=$USER --http-passwd=$usepw -x 16 -s 100 $urlPath | tee /dev/fd/2)
```

The stdout ends up in `var` while `tee` duplicates it to stderr, which displays to your screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.  I see the same behavior as my examples - the variable assignment captures the output so nothing's available until the download completes.

Comment: try --log log.txt and tail log.txt ?