# How to read command output in Bash while command is still running

Tags: bash, shell, udp, sh

I need to read data sent by UDP. I use `nc -ul 50000`. It keeps running even after having received a line. I want to read every line as it arrives.
How can I do that?

An answer to another question on Stackexchange suggested using something like

```
while read VAR
do
my_command
done < <(nc -ul 50000)
```

but that doesn't do the trick... doesn't read anything.
I am really grateful for any help you can provide cause I really don't know how this could be done.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee

Answer (score 1):

You can force a program to use line-buffered or unbuffered output with

`stdbuf -o L nc -ul 50000`

(replace the "L" with "0" (zero) to get fully unbuffered output)

Comment: `stdbuf` is not POSIX, but part of GNU-coreutils.

Comment: `while read IN; do echo $IN; notify-send $IN; done < <(stdbuf -o L nc -ul 50000)`
should then print every arriving text as it arrives, shouldn't it? Unfortunately, I get not output from it.

Comment: Do you know that the nc command is receiving messages? What happens if you just run the `stdbuf -o L nc -ul 50000` command like I had - does it print out messages? (edited to add full command)