# how to both print on terminal and a log file?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

The following line of code writes every printed output in python into the log file:

```
C:...>python myscript.py > myoutput.log
```

Unfortunately, this does **not** print on terminal.

**How can I fix this in a simple way?**

I am using Windows 10. Would it be fixed if I change to Linux based system like Ubuntu?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I am currently using Win10 in my home. But I have ubuntu in my lab. So any solution viable in ubuntu terminal will be also very helpful for me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)

Comment: On a "unixoid system" (e.g. your Ubuntu) there's a `tee` command for that: `python myscript.py | tee myoutput.log`

Comment: I will check right away  on Ubuntu. Thank you very much guys!

Comment: @L3viathan Firstly, I sincerely aprreciate your reply, thank you very much. I just tried your command on both powershell and ubuntu terminal and it works fine. I have one concern though. The printing on the terminal screen is not online. Is this not really easily fixable?

Comment: @jachilles I don't understand the term "online". It's not line-buffered? You can use the command `unbuffer` to fix that, see e.g. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11337041/1016216).

Answer (score 0):

See `Tee-Object` Example 1 in PowerShell. `help Tee-Object -Full`

& python myscript.py | Tee-Object -FilePath '.\myoutput.log'

Answer (score 0):

I got what I exactly wanted according to the comment helps and other stack resources.

```
$ python -u myscript.py | tee myoutput.log
```

Without `-u`, the printing on the terminal screen is not real time.

For window users, simply go to powershell rather than cmd.