# Shell command - to check output immediately and save as a file

Tags: shell

I want to save the terminal output as a file *and* also see the output *immediately*. There are a lot of [related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274168/display-output-from-command-and-save-to-file) but the answers are not satisfying. For example,

```sh
my_command > output.txt
```

does not print output to terminal. Another answer, which is

```sh
my_command | tee output.txt
```

prints output to terminal **after the process is completed, not immediately**. Although I can append each line when I print the output in python code, but this does not seem to be a *right* way to solve issue.

---

Update: it seems that `tee` flushes output to terminal with certain amount of units.

Comment: One possibility is to use something like `script(1)` which will capture the screen output as it is displayed.

Comment: Make sure you read the man page for `script` if you use it -- it is subject to some significant limitations.

Comment: If `tee` output is not printing fast enough, and your command is a python script, you can add the flag `python -u` to unbuffer the output. More info on unbuffered I/O in python: [(python) disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that only works for *python scripts*.
Whenever the script prints something on terminal with `print` function, instead of

```py
print("some message")
```

use

```py
print("some message", flush=True)
```

and with the shell command

```
$ python3 my_script.py |& tee output.txt
```

it worked well.

Comment: For python scripts  you can also use `-u` to disable buffering on python's side: `python3 -u your_program.py | tee output.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`stdfbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) to modify the buffering behavior of the standard streams of a command. Something like

```
stdbuf -o0 your_command | stdbuf -i0 -o0 tee
```

should get rid of the buffering.

Note, this does not work for commands that override the buffering settings of their standard streams, see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337109/14015737).