# tee command isn't showing any output nor writing to a file

Tags: linux, terminal, tee

I am running an A.I. and trying to have the output displayed on the terminal while writing to a .csv file.

The command was something like:

```
$ ./run | tee rdata.csv
```

And nothing happened, no output from the terminal and nothing on the.csv file as well. The program itself ran without a problem. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it print any output when run without piping to `tee`...?

Comment: Yes, the outputs were displayed on the terminal without any issue. Btw I probably should have added that its running on C++

Comment: Why do you think that the programming language matters?

Comment: Does the program produce continuous output without ending? There may be buffering delaying the output.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-in-a-pipeline

Comment: Is the output printed when you pipe it through `cat` or through `more`? The process may check whether its output stream is associated with a terminal and avoid printing anything if it's not (although it would not be a good practice).

Answer (score 0):

try this command it may help you.

```
./run 2>&1 >> rdata.csv
```