Why is my output buffer getting flushed in C++?
For what i know, the differences between this codes:
#include <iostream>
//CODE 1
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl;
    while(1);
    return 0;
}

#include <iostream>
//CODE 2
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hi there \n";
    while(1);
    return 0;
}

Is that, in the 'CODE 1', the endl introduces a newline, but also flushes the output buffer (cout), so, whenever the 'cout' statement gets executed, i will have 'Hi there' printed on the terminal
But, for what i know, in the 'CODE 2', when i have a newline '\n', i dont have a flush in the output buffer, and this output buffer flushing happens whenever i have a 'cin' statement or the program finish its execution, so, why both codes flushes the output buffer (i mean both codes print the messages "Hi there") if only the code 1 shoould do it
Is this a GNU/GCC thing? so if i change to a C++ standard, now, only code 1 should print the message right?
Thanks in advance!

In many implementations, standard output is line-buffered, and writing '\n' causes a flush anyway, std::endl guarantees a flush, not using it does not prohibit a flush.

An infinite loop without side-effects causes undefined behavior.

And how bad can one little infinite loop make things? Pretty bad, it turns out.

@jabaa -- not anymore, The statement of a trivial infinite loop is replaced with a call to the function std​::​this_thread​::​yield ([thread.thread.this])
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.iter.general#3

Groovy, @Gene . When does that kick in? C++26?

@user4581301 - I expect P2809R3 to be in C++26 https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P2809R3.html

Not withstanding at least one proposal that may or may not be in a future C++ standard,  infinite loops with no side-effects currently give undefined behaviour.   In practice, one common optimisation by compilers is to remove them entirely, which is arguably consistent with the "forward progress" guarantee that was introduced in C++11.    Either way, any behaviour either code sample exhibits (with any compiler) is correct according to the standard.

@Gene So, were talking about a proposal that could come into C++26. I would say my statement  "An infinite loop without side-effects causes undefined behavior" is correct.  Your answer "not anymore" could be correct in 2 years.

Ok so changing the infinite loop to a
'system("pause");
generates the same result, so, as said by @Avi Berger, with the endl i guarantee to have a flush but with just \n is implementation dependant right?

If you pipe the output into a file, you should observe a different behavior, at least on Linux. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-in-a-pipeline

there are several factors affecting when you see the output in the terminal, flush() is just one of them, see this discussion: https://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/192071/#msg925979

"differences between this codes" - Program code is uncountable.

@MikeNakis It's probably better to link webster, that article is outright inprecise. THings like  sheep or deer aren't uncountable, just standard plural form either is a homograph with singular or there is no singular. And some countables also can be used as uncountables if it is used in meaning "a bulk amount of" which they uses as example, sheep, fish a nd bread is the case, deer used to be (was meant any animal) . "code" is rare true uncountable.

@Swift-FridayPie that's my personal blog. Thank you for bringing this to my attention, I will look into it and make corrections.
