How can I tame pytest's separators in the output without losing progress updates?
pytest output has lots of headers that span the width of the terminal:
========================================= FAILURES =========================================

____________________________________ test_advanced_fail ____________________________________

If I filter them out after collecting the output from the command, I no longer get the real-time progress updates to the terminal.
Is there any way to modify the appearance of these separators without losing the ability to see real-time running of the tests?

Hi. You want tomodify pytest, or you want to filter the output?  In what environment? In python? In bash? In windows cmd? Is this question related to python? My 5 min search: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/_io/terminalwriter.py#L135 also https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/7add2af7087dc32af19a38f5950a5b64a19d1de5/testing/conftest.py#L29 . I would guess set your COLUMNS properly.

Some of them I just want to eliminate. Like, I don't need to see FAILURES. I know they are failures. Also don't need to see "test session starts".
It's just useless noise.
For other headers, better use of blanks line and a splash of color for headings to help provide visual seapration would be much better.
I'm using pytest with python on terminal on mac.

Sure, so how do you want to solve the problem? Is there any way to modify Yes, pytest is open source. You can patch pytest and post a patch upstream or keep it to yourself. You can filter the output in a program written by you. If you are asking how to filter output without buffering in shell, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-in-a-pipeline

I ended up generating a script with ChatGPT that lets me keep the progress bar and then dumps out the rest of the content line-by-line. I can't post here but here's a ink: https://paste.debian.net/1331042/
