# Why does stdout need explicit flushing when redirected to file?

Tags: c, linux, stdout

The behaviour of `printf()` seems to depend on the location of `stdout`.

1. If `stdout` is sent to the console, then `printf()` is line-buffered and is flushed after a newline is printed.
2. If `stdout` is redirected to a file, the buffer is not flushed unless `fflush()` is called.
3. Moreover, if `printf()` is used before `stdout` is redirected to file, subsequent writes (to the file) are line-buffered and are flushed after newline.

When is `stdout` line-buffered, and when does `fflush()` need to be called?

#### Minimal example of each:

```
void RedirectStdout2File(const char* log_path) {
    int fd = open(log_path, O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO);
    if (fd != STDOUT_FILENO) close(fd);
}

int main_1(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /* Case 1: stdout is line-buffered when run from console */
    printf("No redirect; printed immediately\n");
    sleep(10);
}

int main_2a(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /* Case 2a: stdout is not line-buffered when redirected to file */
    RedirectStdout2File(argv[0]);
    printf("Will not go to file!\n");
    RedirectStdout2File("/dev/null");
}
int main_2b(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /* Case 2b: flushing stdout does send output to file */
    RedirectStdout2File(argv[0]);
    printf("Will go to file if flushed\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    RedirectStdout2File("/dev/null");
}

int main_3(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /* Case 3: printf before redirect; printf is line-buffered after */
    printf("Before redirect\n");
    RedirectStdout2File(argv[0]);
    printf("Does go to file!\n");
    RedirectStdout2File("/dev/null");
}
```

Comment: You should check for errors from all system calls.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks for your suggestion. I just remove the checking code here to make code more readable. Error checking dose not fix my problem.

Comment: So I guess none of the functions actually returns an error?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Flushing for `stdout` is determined by its buffering behaviour. The buffering can be set to three modes: `_IOFBF` (full buffering: waits until `fflush()` if possible), `_IOLBF` (line buffering: newline triggers automatic flush), and `_IONBF` (direct write always used). "Support for these characteristics is implementation-deﬁned, and may be affected via the `setbuf()` and `setvbuf()` functions." [C99:7.19.3.3]

"At program startup, three text streams are predeﬁned and need not be opened explicitly
— standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing
conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). As initially
opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard
output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer
to an interactive device." [C99:7.19.3.7]

#### Explanation of observed behaviour

So, what happens is that the implementation does something platform-specific to decide whether `stdout` is going to be line-buffered. In most libc implementations, this test is done when the stream is first used.

1. Behaviour #1 is easily explained: when the stream is for an interactive device, it is line-buffered, and the `printf()` is flushed automatically.
2. Case #2 is also now expected: when we redirect to a file, the stream is fully buffered and will not be flushed except with `fflush()`, unless you write gobloads of data to it.
3. Finally, we understand case #3 too for implementations that only perform the check on the underlying fd once. Because we forced stdout's buffer to be initialised in the first `printf()`, stdout acquired the line-buffered mode. When we swap out the fd to go to file, it's still line-buffered, so the data is flushed automatically.

#### Some actual implementations

Each libc has latitude in how it interprets these requirements, since C99 doesn't specify what an "interactive device" is, nor does [POSIX's stdio entry](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) extend this (beyond requiring stderr to be open for reading).

1. Glibc. See [filedoalloc.c:L111](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/filedoalloc.c;h=c9b0f01722a1c5b65f4e2df24e951154d133ae21;hb=HEAD#l111). Here we use `stat()` to test if the fd is a tty, and set the buffering mode accordingly. (This is called from fileops.c.) `stdout` initially has a null buffer, and it's allocated on the first use of the stream based on the characteristics of fd 1.
2. BSD libc. Very similar, but much cleaner code to follow! See [this line in makebuf.c](http://bxr.su/o/lib/libc/stdio/makebuf.c#__swhatbuf)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on error checking and leak fixing. But I still don't understand why I need to fflush here. And why printing some message before redirecting can fix the problem.

Comment: @Patrick Ah, I see. In that case, dupe of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin#comment5855685_1716621

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have "\n" in my code, should it trigger flush?

Comment: See comment linked to: this is expected. I've just looked up the glibc and BSD libc source lines to show you; I'll edit the answer later.

Comment: For reference: BSD libc is [makebuf.c](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/stdio/makebuf.c?rev=1.7)

Comment: Another question is that when I replaced fflush(stdout) with fsync(STDOUT_FILENO), the message was still not redirected to the file. Do you know why?

Comment: Ok, last answer! fsync, fstat, ftruncate etc are one family of functions (in man section 2); totally unrelated to fopen, fprintf, fflush (section 3). fsync is in the kernel, and knows nothing about libc's stdio buffers, which are in your application.

Comment: sorry for one more question. Why the close function on STDOUT_FILENO not trigger flushing?

Comment: I get it now. close is a system function, it has no knowledge of libc buffer either.

Answer (score 4):

Your are wrongly combining buffered and unbuffered IO functions. Such a combination must be done very carefully especially when the code has to be portable. (and it is bad to write unportable code...)
**It is certainly best to avoid combining buffered and unbuffered IO on the same file descriptor.**

**Buffered IO:** `fprintf()`, `fopen()`, `fclose()`, `freopen()`...

**Unbuffered IO:** `write()`, `open()`, `close()`, `dup()`...

When you use `dup2()` to redirect stdout. The function is not aware of the buffer which was filled by `fprintf()`. So when `dup2()` closes the old descriptor 1 it does not flush the buffer and the content could be flushed to a different output. In your case 2a it was sent to `/dev/null`.

### The solution

In your case it is best to use `freopen()` instead of `dup2()`. This solves all your problems:

1. It flushes the buffers of the original `FILE` stream. (case 2a)
2. It sets the buffering mode according to the newly opened file. (case 3)

Here is the correct implementation of your function:

```
void RedirectStdout2File(const char* log_path) {
    if(freopen(log_path, "a+", stdout) == NULL) err(EXIT_FAILURE, NULL);
}
```

Unfortunately with buffered IO you cannot directly set permissions of a newly created file. You have to use other calls to change the permissions or you can use unportable glibc extensions. See the [`fopen() man page`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).

Answer (score 0):

You should not close the file descriptor, so remove `close(fd)` and close 
`stdout_bak_fd` if you want the message to be print only in the file.