# Win32 GUI C(++) app redirect both stdout and stderr to the same file on disk

Tags: c++, c, windows, stdout, dup2

I'm creating a Windows service, which cannot have an associated console. Therefore I want to redirect stdout and stderr to a (the same) file. Here is what I discovered so far:

1. Redirecting `cout` and `cerr` in C++ can be done by [changing the buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151286/4454665), but this does not affect C I/O like `puts` or Windows I/O handles.
2. Hence we can use [`freopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/freopen-s-wfreopen-s) to reopen stdout or stderr as a file like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13888242/4454665), but we cannot specify the same file twice.
3. To still use the same file for both we can redirect stderr to stdout using [`dup2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dup-dup2) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15156927/4454665).

So far so good, and when we run this code with `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` (project properties → Linker → System) everything works fine:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

void doit()
{
    FILE *stream;
    if (_wfreopen_s(&stream, L"log.log", L"w", stdout)) __debugbreak();
    // Also works as service when uncommenting this line: if (_wfreopen_s(&stream, L"log2.log", L"w", stderr)) __debugbreak();
    if (_dup2(_fileno(stdout), _fileno(stderr)))
    {
        const auto err /*EBADF if service; hover over in debugger*/ = errno;
        __debugbreak();
    }

    // Seemingly can be left out for console applications
    if (!SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_get_osfhandle(_fileno(stdout))))) __debugbreak();
    if (!SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_get_osfhandle(_fileno(stderr))))) __debugbreak();

    if (_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT) == -1) __debugbreak();
    if (_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_WTEXT) == -1) __debugbreak();

    std::wcout << L"1☺a" << std::endl;
    std::wcerr << L"1☺b" << std::endl;

    _putws(L"2☺a");
    fflush(stdout);
    fputws(L"2☺b\n", stderr);
    fflush(stderr);

    const std::wstring a3(L"3☺a\n"), b3(L"3☺b\n");
    if (!WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), a3.c_str(), a3.size() * sizeof(wchar_t), nullptr, nullptr))
        __debugbreak();
    if (!WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), b3.c_str(), b3.size() * sizeof(wchar_t), nullptr, nullptr))
        __debugbreak();
}

int        main() { doit(); }
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int) { return doit(), 0; }
```

This nicely writes the following text to `log.log`:

```
1☺a
1☺b
2☺a
2☺b
3☺a
3☺b
```

(*Of course* we want emoji, so we need some sort of unicode. In this case we use wide characters, which means we need to use `setmode` or else everything will mess up. You may also need to save the cpp file in an encoding that MSVC understands, e.g. UTF-8 *with* signature.)

But now back to the original problem: doing this as a service without console, or, equivalent but easier to debug, a GUI app (`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`).
The problem is that in this case **`dup2` fails** because `fileno(stderr)` is not a valid file descriptor, because the app initially has no associated streams. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51822723/4454665), `fileno(stderr) == -2` in this case.

Note that when we first open stderr as another file using `freopen`, everything works fine, but we created a dummy empty file.

So now my question is: *what is the best way to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same file in an application which initially has no streams?*

Just to recap: the problem is that [when `stdout` or `stderr` is not associated with an output stream, `fileno` returns -2](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fileno#return-value), so we cannot pass it to `dup2`.

(I do not want to change the code used for the actual printing, because that might mean that some output produced by external functions will not be redirected.)

Comment: What If you simply open a file with CreateFile, and use its handle to SetStdHandle()?

Comment: As I assume you want to log debug and event data in those files, I recommend using the windows events if you really want a nice behaving production grade windows service. That API is quite complex so I would further recommend Boost Log. You C code would have to call some C linked functions offered by your C++ code then. Otherwise, you will never leave the hackinsh world.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis You would say that it would be that easy, but this does not actually redirect 1☺ and 2☺, only 3☺.

Comment: @Superlokkus You mean [Windows Event Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/wes/windows-event-log)? Yeah I wanted to do that later, but saw it was quite complex indeed. I might check out Boost Log (haven't worked with Boost at all yet though). Also I don't think this would work with unmodified printing code, right? And what do you mean with "You C code would have to call some C linked functions offered by your C++ code then"?

Comment: You can replace the global `cout` and `cerr` streams with boost log ones at startup, but as you are right to fear is that would not cut it: For nice logging, the logging code should decide for an altert or log level, and not directly print it somewhere. It should make a function call with the level information and log line. 
Your C++ code could do this to boost log directly but, you want a nice own simple between layer.
I assume you have much legacy code, with some C code, you can't compile as C++ translation units (compile .c s with the C++ compiler). But you can call your own simle layer.

Comment: @Superlokkus Thanks for the information! I don't really have any legacy code (because this is just my own small project I'm working on), so I could replace most code to make it work, but I think it would be nice to have something to redirect all output (including output of CRT debugging functions etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works and does not create a temporary file `log2.log`. Instead of this file, we can open `NUL` (Windows's `/dev/null`), so the code becomes:

```cpp
FILE *stream;
if (_wfreopen_s(&stream, L"log.log", L"w", stdout)) __debugbreak();
if (freopen_s(&stream, "NUL", "w", stderr)) __debugbreak();
if (_dup2(_fileno(stdout), _fileno(stderr))) __debugbreak();

if (!SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_get_osfhandle(_fileno(stdout))))) __debugbreak();
if (!SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_get_osfhandle(_fileno(stderr))))) __debugbreak();

if (_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT) == -1) __debugbreak();
if (_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_WTEXT) == -1) __debugbreak();
```

This makes sure that `_fileno(stderr)` is not `-2` anymore so we can use `dup2`.

There might be a more elegant solution (not sure), but this works and does not create a dummy empty file (also not one named `NUL`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a program that creates a file for writing and then uses `CreateProcess` and setting `stdout` and `stderr` for the process to the `HANDLE` of the created file. This example just starts itself with a dummy argument to make it write a lot of things to `stdout` and `stderr` that will be written to `output.txt`.

```
// RedirectStd.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

#include <Windows.h>

struct SecAttrs_t : public SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {
    SecAttrs_t() : SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES{ 0 } {
        nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    }
    operator SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* () { return this;  }
};

struct StartupInfo_t : public STARTUPINFO {
    StartupInfo_t(HANDLE output) : STARTUPINFO{ 0 } {
        cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
        dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        hStdOutput = output;
        hStdError = output;
    }
    operator STARTUPINFO* () { return this; }
};

int cppmain(const std::string_view program, std::vector<std::string_view> args) {
    if (args.size() == 0) {
        // no arguments, create a file and start a new process
        SecAttrs_t sa;

        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"output.txt",
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            sa, // lpSecurityAttributes
            CREATE_ALWAYS, // dwCreationDisposition
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, // dwFlagsAndAttributes
            NULL // dwFlagsAndAttributesparameter
        );
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return 1;

        StartupInfo_t su(hFile); // set output handles to hFile
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        std::wstring commandline = L"RedirectStd.exe dummy";
        BOOL bCreated = CreateProcess(
            NULL,
            commandline.data(),
            NULL, // lpProcessAttributes
            NULL, // lpThreadAttributes
            TRUE, // bInheritHandles
            0, // dwCreationFlags
            NULL, // lpEnvironment
            NULL, // lpCurrentDirectory
            su, // lpStartupInfo
            &pi
        );
        if (bCreated == 0) return 2;
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread); // no need for this

        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE); // wait for the process to finish         
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    else {
        // called with an argument, output stuff to stdout and stderr 
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
            std::cout << "stdout\n";
            std::cerr << "stderr\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return cppmain(argv[0], { argv + 1, argv + argc });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I don't think this will work in my case, because as a service you have to call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` (and I don't think this will work in a child process). Anyway, creating a new process seems a bit unnecessary, but this solution might be enough for some cases.

Comment: @SWdV Ok, i see what you mean. And a simple `if (_fileno(stdout) < 0) AllocConsole();` won't help I guess?

Comment: It does not, because normally services cannot have consoles (and I wouldn't really want one here)

Comment: I know they don't have std handles per default, but `AllocConsole` could be a way to create those handles so you can use `SetStdHandle` on `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` and `STD_ERROR_HANDLE` and put your file handle there instead. .

Comment: Did the `AllocConsole` call succeed and did the two `SetStdHandle` calls succeed?

Comment: AllocConsole succeeded, strangely enough, but what should I give to SetStdHandle? -2 to a handle won't work

Comment: You give it the handle of the file you want to write to, `hFile` in my example.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really see how that would work. Would you mind posting a full snippet?

Comment: @SWdV  I was thinking something along these lines: https://godbolt.org/z/govKF-  It does not work when run as a normal program though, but perhaps it'll work when starting without a console associated with it.

Comment: Unfortunately this also only redirects 3☺, like when you do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939802/win32-gui-c-app-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-the-same-file-on-disk#comment100420060_56939802).

Comment: @SWdV What is 3?

Comment: Ok, I wonder if you shouldn't separate the OS interaction layer from the code doing all the services work (and print logs) by creating a separate process after all. At least that way, you'll be able to easily provide the sub process with stdout/stderr handles as I showed in the answer. Your parent process will only need to wait for service events and to start/stop the sub process.