# stdout of spawned process works strange when being piped

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, unix

My goal is to save the session of some process execution to json (smth like `[{ type: 'stdout', data: 'What's your name?' }, { type: 'stdin', data: 'Alex.' }, { type: 'stdout', data: 'Hi, Alex!' }]`). I decided to do it with nodejs, but I've run into some problems. The stdout of spawned process works differently when being piped and when being inherited. So, for example I have this C code (simple guess number game) compiled to `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  int random_num = 0;
  int guessed_num = 0;
  int counter = 0;

  srand(time(NULL));
  random_num = rand() % 10 + 1;

  printf("Guess my number! ");

  while(1) {
    counter++;

    scanf("%d", &guessed_num);

    if (guessed_num == random_num) {
      printf("You guessed correctly in %d tries! Congratulations!\n", counter);
      break;
    }

    if (guessed_num < random_num)
      printf("Your guess is too low. Guess again. ");

    if (guessed_num > random_num)
      printf("Your guess is too high. Guess again. ");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And this JavaScript code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('./main', { stdio: 'inherited' });
```

The result of execution of this JavaScript code will be:

```
Guess my number! 1
Your guess is too low. Guess again. 2
Your guess is too low. Guess again. 3
You guessed correctly in 3 tries! Congratulations!
```

However, when `stdio` is `inherited`, I can't attach to any of process streams and save the data to json. So I tried this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('./main', { stdio: 'pipe' });
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) { process.stdout.write(data) });
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) { child.stdin.write(data) });
```

And get this as a result of execution:

```
1
2
3
Guess my number! Your guess is too low. Guess again. Your guess is too low. Guess again. You guessed correctly in 3 tries! Congratulations!
```

The stdout of child process is somehow hangs when the child process is waiting for input. Probably it has to do something with event-loop, but I'm not sure. Anyway, the behavior of `inherited` and `pipe` is very different and it seems wrong...

What can I do about it? Maybe there is some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `inherited` mode, the C program inherits of a descriptor bound to the terminal. The terminal being an interactive device, it automatically sets the buffering of the `printf()` functions to `stdout` to be line buffered (i.e. the buffer is flushed when a new line is encountered).

OTOH, in `pipe` mode, the libc doesn't detect an interactive device, and switches to full buffering (i.e. the buffer is only flushed when its full or when `fflush()` is called.

A workaround would be to call `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf()` call or to disable buffering for `stdout` alltogether: `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13933741/451641) for a full explanation of pipes vs. terminal buffering, including an example of libc determining the buffering for `stdout`.

Comment: Thank you, it explains a lot. I didn't pay attention to this thing in Node documentation: "Note, however, that some programs use line-buffered I/O internally. While that does not affect Node.js, it can mean that data sent to the child process may not be immediately consumed." Another option I see is to use a PTY (e.g. `pty.js`), but in this case the ability to distinguish stdout and stderr will be lost. So, it seems impossible to emulate an interactive device and distinguish stdout and stderr streams.

Comment: However, running this same C program within a Docker container with (dockerode)[https://github.com/apocas/dockerode] it's actually possible to demultiplex streams. I've read the source of it and it seems that it connects to `/var/run/docker.sock` socket and then demultiplex the stream that Docker exports.  So it seems that Docker handles it somehow... I just don't understand how :)

Comment: Wow, I found an easier solution. `spawn('stdbuf', ['-i0', '-o0', '-e0', './main'], { stdio: 'pipe' })` works just fine! Changing C code is fine, but I don't always have sources of it, so I think this solution is more appropriate. Anyway, thanks a lot!