# when stdout is redirected to a file fflush is not enough

Tags: c, stdout, fflush, freopen

I have a C program with 9 calls to printf and I need it to run on a remote server for several days. So I decided to redirect the stdout to a file to check the progresses:

```
FILE *foutput=freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
```

After some debugging I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932932/why-does-stdout-need-explicit-flushing-when-redirected-to-file) and used

`fflush(foutput)`

and from what I can see in the link, all the buffering are right to me (I have a newline command at the end of each print): right in the sense that I expect the print to be effectively executed and to find them on output.txt, but this is not happening.

What may be the problem?

I want you to note that following works:

```
  foutput=freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
  printf("first print\n");
  fflush(foutput);
  fclose(foutput);
```

but I'd like to avoid the call to `freopen` each time.

Comment: "but this is not happening." --> what is happening?  How did you determine what is happening as the file appears to not be closed when you are testing the text?  I suspect your output file is not a _share-able_ mode.

Comment: why not let your OS deal with the output? If you're using linux/mac you could use tmux or screen to run your code in the remote location. With these programs you can scroll through the output. Or just use a redirection like `$ my-program > mylog.txt` and when you log in, you just inspect `mylog.txt`.

Comment: @chux is not happening that the output is printed on the file: I open it and there's nothing.

Comment: @Pablo I'm not familiar with the > command. I'm gonna take a look.

Comment: There are program buffers and there are OS buffers. Reading from MSVC documentation, it seems that `fflush` flushes the program buffers but by default does not instruct the OS to flush the OS buffers for the file. However, upon an `fclose` the locks on the file are removed and the file is available for anyone else. Hence the OS flushes its buffers now too.

Comment: I'd go with the solution using `fclose`  each time. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thank you for the explanation. Is there a way to force the OS buffers to be flushed? However, I can't understand why in the link I posted the simple solution was working.

Comment: From MSVC: "_...turn buffering off with the `setvbuf` function..._"

Comment: @MichaelWalz It is not very elegant and, most iportant, ther's always the risk for the file to be not opened

Comment: What happens if you open the file with `fopen` instead of `freopen` and write to it with `fprintf` instead of `printf`? Maybe it makes a difference. What is your operating system?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. However, your idea works. I was just seeking for an explanation of something that seems correct but doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting, on my Windows 10 it works exactly as you expect.

Comment: On Ubuntu, your program ought to be able to call `fsync()` after `fflush()` to ensure that the OS-level buffers are also flushed.  However, I find it surprising that such an action would be needed, to the extent that I suspect some other factor is involved.  Even without the `fsync()`, the system should not keep the data buffered long, and Linux does not implement or require file "sharing modes" such as Windows has.  (`fsync()` is a POSIX function, not one specified by C istelf.)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, `setvbuf()` controls C-level stream buffers.  It has nothing to do with OS-level buffering (or at least C does not specify anything at that level).  Thus, turning off buffering via `setvbuf()` would remove the need for an `fflush()`, but there's no reason to expect it to help when `fflush()` is being called anyway.