# Why is my Python script not writing to file when it is backgrounded it in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I can do:

```
python script.py > logfile 2>&1
```

and once I kill it using ctrl c I can see changes to the logfile. However, when I do:

```
python script.py > logfile 2>&1 &
```

I can't see any changes to the log file . How can I background my script and still have it write to the logfile?

Comment: Buffering. Explicitly flush.

Comment: By the way -- the typical reason this works differently between going to stdout and going to a file is that the standard C library's behavior differs based on whether the output descriptor being written to is a TTY; TTY output is line-buffered or unbuffered by default, whereas output to a file is not. (I say "typical" because the Python runtime may do its own thing rather than leaning on the C library here, but the end effect is similar).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your writes aren't going into the ether -- they're getting buffered. After a graceful shutdown (SIGTERM, not SIGKILL), you should see content in the file then as well.

Alternately, you can explicitly flush:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

...or tell Python to run in unbuffered mode:

```
python -u yourscript.py
```

or start your script with

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
```

...to ensure that content is written. This will, of course, have a performance penalty, since your script will be trying to perform IO more frequently.

---

(As an aside, `#!/usr/bin/env python -u` **is not** guaranteed to work: Only a command name and a single argument are guaranteed to be passed through from a shebang line to a command that's run; your operating system may or may not honor more than that).

Comment: thanks! for non python commands I found: [how to flush](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/bash-how-to-flush-output-to-a-file-while-running)

Comment: The accepted answer there on that question boils down to "you need to solve it within the bounds of the specific program you're running" -- not tremendously helpful. `stdbuf` is a GNU extension, and `unbuffer` is packaged with `expect` -- not a POSIX-standardized tool. There aren't really good generic answers here.

Comment: Personally, if I wanted to point to a good generic reference, I'd make that BashFAQ #009: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

Answer (score 0):

`command 2> error.txt 1> output.txt`
this worked for me, more in https://linuxize.com/post/bash-redirect-stderr-stdout/

I find it diffcult to understand why `command > logfile 2>&1` did not work