# How to use stdbuf on a bash function

Tags: bash

We can use stdbuf on a regular command, e.g.

```
stdbuf -o 0 echo aaa
```

However I can't use it on a bash function, e.g.

```
function tmpf() { echo aaa; }
stdbuf -o 0 tmpf
```

What's the reason for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that bash functions are internal to the bash session. `stdbuf` and utilities like that are separate programs with no access to the shell session, and indeed without any knowledge of bash. So it can only run executables.

Because bash has a few tricks up its sleeve, you can *export* a bash function -- like exporting an environment variable -- which will make the function accessible to bash processes run in children. So you can do this:

```
function tmpf() { echo aaa; }
export -f tmpf
stdbuf -o 0 bash -c 'tmpf'
```

but even there, you need to get `stdbuf` to execute a child `bash` in order to call the function.