# Force flushing from inside bash script code to a stdout file

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to flush to stdout the output of a bioinformatic software written on Python code (Ete-Toolkit software). I tried the command (stdbuf) detailed on [Force flushing of output to a file while bash script is still running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/force-flushing-of-output-to-a-file-while-bash-script-is-still-running) but does not work because I have seen that stdbuf command it's only possible to execute from shell and not from bash([How to use stdbuf on a bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348559/how-to-use-stdbuf-on-a-bash-function)).

Moreover from Python I discovered the following function that maybe could be interesting:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

But I don't know how can I implement inside the next bash script attached below.

The purpose is that if I only use the options -o and -e in the bash script (as you can see) the output is printed to logs_40markers in a not continuos manner which does not permits me to see the error. I can do it working directly from shell but my internet connection is not stable and practically each night there are a power outage and I have to restart again the command that will takes minimun one week.

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N tree
#$ -o logs_40markers
#$ -e logs_40markers
#$ -q all.q@compute-0-3
#$ -l mf=100G

stdbuf -oL

module load apps/etetoolkit-3.1.2

export QT_QPA_PLATFORM='offscreen'

ete3 build -w mafft_default-none-none-none -m sptree_fasttree_all -o provaflush --cogs coglist_species_filtered.txt -a multifasta_speciesunique.fa  --clearall --cpu 40 

&> logs_40markers
```

Thanks on advance if someone can give me some guide/advice,

Have a nice day,

Thank you,

Maggi

Answer (score 0):

one informatician colleague of me solved the problem using the PYTHONUNBUFFERED command.

#!/bin/bash
#$ -N tree
#$ -o logs_40markers
#$ -e logs_40markers
#$ -q all.q@compute-0-3
#$ -l mf=100G

```
module load apps/etetoolkit-3.1.2

export QT_QPA_PLATFORM='offscreen'
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED="TRUE"

ete3 build -w mafft_default-none-none-none -m sptree_fasttree_all -o provaflush --cogs coglist_species_filtered.txt -a multifasta_speciesunique.fa  --clearall --cpu 40 --v 4
```

To check the current situation of the process,
type in the shell:

`tail output.log file -f` (means follow)

I hope that someone could find this solution helpful