# Periodic acess of continuously updating file?

Tags: terminal

I have a program (c++) that outputs data to the terminal. I run it on a machine that I SSH to. I need to be able to:

1. Run the program after I close my session
2. Acess the data that has been output so far, while the program continues to output data.

Right now, I have been doing this:

```
nohup ./freqnew <testparams.txt &> testrun3.out&
```

It's almost what I want. It puts the data from the program into the file testrun3.out, and will run in the background after I close my terminal window. However, until the program is finished, the .out file is completely empty.

When I start doing long runs, they could take weeks, but I need to periodically access the data to make sure it's plausible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `flush()` to push your data to disk:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/

Comment: So I would need to write to the file within the c++ program?

Comment: @JeremiahGelb Do you print newlines ever? as in write `std::endl` or `\n` to file? If so it is likley you are already flushing and you have another problem.

Comment: I didn't notice that you were redirecting the output (vs writing it yourself within the program).  See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the output the of program, you can use `tee` or `script` to redirect the output the a file and those apparently have better flushing capabilities ([like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/force-flushing-of-output-to-a-file-while-bash-script-is-still-running)).

That also lets you see the output on the screen as well as saving it to disk (if that's a desirable feature).

```
nohup ./freqnew <testparams.txt 2>&1 | testrun3.out
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to redirect `cout` to the file that you want:

```
std::ofstream out("out.txt");
std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //save old buf
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cout to out.txt!
```