# Bash output to screen and logfile differently

Tags: linux, bash

I have been trying to get a bash script to output different things on the terminal and logfile but am unsure of what command to use.

For example,

```
#!/bin/bash
freespace=$(df -h / | grep -E "/" | awk '{print $4}')
greentext="\033[32m"
bold="\033[1m"
normal="\033[0m"
logdate=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
logfile="$logdate"_report.log

exec > >(tee -i $logfile)

echo -e $bold"Quick system report for "$greentext"$HOSTNAME"$normal
printf "\tSystem type:\t%s\n" $MACHTYPE
printf "\tBash Version:\t%s\n" $BASH_VERSION
printf "\tFree Space:\t%s\n" $freespace
printf "\tFiles in dir:\t%s\n" $(ls | wc -l)
printf "\tGenerated on:\t%s\n" $(date +"%m/%d/%y") # US date format
echo -e $greentext"A summary of this info has been saved to $logfile"$normal
```

I want to omit the last output (echo "A summary...") in the logfile while displaying it in the terminal. Is there a command to do so? It would be great if a general solution can be provided instead of a specific one because I want to apply this to other scripts.

EDIT 1 (after applying >&6):

```
Files in dir:   7
A summary of this info has been saved to 20160915_report.log
Generated on:   09/15/16
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Don't forget to check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more site-specific details (and a badge :) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
exec 6>&1    # save the existing stdout
exec > >(tee -i $logfile)   # like you had it
#... all your outputs
echo -e $greentext"A summary of this info has been saved to $logfile"$normal >&6   
    # writes to the original stdout, saved in file descriptor 6  ------------^^^
```

The `>&6` sends `echo`'s output to the saved file descriptor 6 (the terminal, if you're running this from an interactive shell) rather than to the output path set up by `tee` (which is on file descriptor 1).  Tested on bash 4.3.46.

References: ["Using exec"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html) and ["I/O Redirection"](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

**Edit** As OP found, the `>&6` message is not guaranteed to appear after the lines printed by `tee` off stdout.  One option is to use `script`, e.g., as in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429951/2877364), instead of `tee`, and then print the final message outside of the `script`.  Per [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html), the `stdbuf` answers to that question won't work with `tee`.

Try a dirty hack:

```
#... all your outputs
echo >&6  # <-- New line
echo -e $greentext ... >&6
```

Or, equally hackish, **(Note that, per OP, this worked)**

```
#... all your outputs
sleep 0.25s   # or whatever time you want  <-- New line
echo -e ... >&6
```

Comment: It worked but for some reason the last echo output got shifted upwards in the terminal. I'm also using 4.3.46 :(

Comment: @Larrrrrrrrrry Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39515426/edit) to include a bit more detail, or perhaps a screenshot - what do you mean by "shifted upwards in the terminal"?

Comment: I edited my post, under EDIT 1. The output that says "A summary..." shifted upwards instead of being the last output.

Comment: @Larrrrrrrrrry Turns out that's a hard problem to solve in the type of situation you have here.  I added some thoughts and links.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second addition worked. The first addition only created an empty line between the "Files in dir" and the "A summary..." without solving the problem.

Comment: Have you considered using printf over echo for the last line? Since printf is buffered and echo not, it could explain the swap.

Comment: @Larrrrrrrrrry Check out fboule's comment, in case you haven't seen it yet.  That would be (I think) `printf '%s' "${greentext}A summary...${normal}" >&6`