# Synchronous pipe in command line

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have two commands: foo and bar.

I want to execute both such that the output of foo is "redirected" to the input of bar. NOT only that though, I also want each byte written to foo's output stream to be directly/instantly written to bar's input stream.

If I use the command:

```
foo | bar
```

then the foo must terminate/exit before bar starts reading its input stream. I want bar to start reading its input stream in the same time the foo writes its output stream.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194279/6746785) answer here, if I understand correctly, states that there is a limit in the number of bytes buffered by the pipe and when they are filled then the pipe is "flushed" to the input stream of bar Maybe this limit can be reduced to '1' somehow?

Comment: I guess your problem is more related to buffered I/O than to synchronicity. Can you control both programs? If you can only control `bar.exe` I'm afraid there is nothing you can do.

Comment: There are named pipes in unix [link](http://vincebuffalo.org/blog/2013/08/08/using-names-pipes-and-process-substitution-in-bioinformatics.html) But I haven't heard of something similar in Windowss

Comment: @dimirsen Is there any way to make named pipes unbuffered?

Comment: Side note:  Please don't use the `.exe` extension in UNIX context. UNIX does not detect binaries based on file extensions, and most to all UNIX binaries don't have extensions. That means `foo.exe` becomes `foo`.

Comment: Paulo, [link](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P57906)

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes. I'l change my question.

Comment: I did it already for you ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl A ok..

Comment: See this post as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/force-flushing-of-output-to-a-file-while-bash-script-is-still-running

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You wrote:

> `foo` must terminate/exit before `bar` starts reading its input stream. I want `bar` to start reading its input stream in the same time the `foo` writes its output stream.

The assumption is not true. `foo` is not required to terminate before it's output gets passed to `bar`. True is that the glibc (assuming that both `foo` and `bar` are linked to it) performs output buffering. Unless the output of `foo` goes to a terminal, the output gets written to a buffer and this buffer gets flushed when it  reaches a certain size. If the output of `foo` is so small that the buffer size won't get reached, then yes, the buffer will get flushed once `foo` exits.

You can adjust the buffer size using the `stdbuf` command. The following command won't buffer `foo`'s output:

```
stdbuf -o0 foo | bar
```