# How to flush piped output from stdout in Nodejs when directed to file

Tags: node.js, linux

Simple example:

```
 node  someCode.js|grep "someString"
```

Displays someString as it is written out.

Now

```
  node someCode.js|grep "someString"  > /tmp/someFile &
```

In another window:

```
ls -l /tmp/someFile
```

shows 0 bytes... so I cannot cat it to see its content.
I know that process.stdout.write is a stream that is flushed immediately upon write...

What do I need to do to get the output file updated with content as it is written out?  There are complicated ways like writing to UNIX sockets and creating a custom UNIX-socket based cat-like program but thats too heavy for this simple requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is more of a Linux than a Node.js question. The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/force-flushing-of-output-to-a-file-while-bash-script-is-still-running). Its not the accepted answer but one with the maximum votes. So my command looks like:

```
    node someCode.js|stdbuf -oL grep "someString"  > /tmp/someFile &
```

One can monitor the progress now in /tmp/someFile as lines are written out. With the **L** option strings are written as **L**ine-buffered. I will try to edit the question to add Linux as another tag.