# Force flush Python-part of Bash-script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, buffer, flush

I have a simple Bash-script that spend more than 99 % of its time on executing a Python application (the script is just a wrapper that feeds this Python script files in a for-loop and renames the output files). I have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/force-flushing-of-output-to-a-file-while-bash-script-is-still-running) and have looked at the answers but don't understand how to use them in my context.

I think I need to apply the principles in the answers to that question inside my script, on the line that executes the Python script, but how?

My script as pseudo-code:

```
for file in "$directory"; do
    pythonscript "$file" >> "log.txt"; then
done
```

I want to flush the pythonscript-line every minute, every line of output it produces or similar, it doesn't matter that much (typically execution takes several hours, I just want to be able to track the output "reasonable" frequently).

Comment: Dump questions, why are u not move whole Logic into the Python script itself, like get all files and iterate eg call your function and just adding logging Into the Python script, that way you dont need to mix Python and bash

Comment: @Christoph Hadn't thought about that, and it makes some sense if I had written the Python application, but it's external and is updated on a regular basis, which means that I would have to apply the modification every time it's updated.

Comment: The [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845184/1745001) to [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/force-flushing-of-output-to-a-file-while-bash-script-is-still-running) says that given a script `/homedir/MyScript` that you want to run unbuffered you should call is as `stdbuf -oL /homedir/MyScript` instead. Your script is `pythonscript "$file"` so call it as `stdbuf -oL pythonscript "$file"` instead. See https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation for more info on `stdbuf`.

Comment: By the way consider using `for file in "$directory"; do whatever; done >log.txt` instead of `for file in "$directory"; do whatever >> log.txt; done` so you only open the output file once, and `for file in "$directory"` is confusing terminology at best or simply a bug, depending on what it's meant to do.

Comment: @EdMorton I am on a Mac and don't seem to have `stdbuf` (despite installing `GNU core utils` from MacPorts).

Comment: Google is your friend. The first hit to https://www.google.com/search?q=macos+stdbuf is https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193141/to-use-stdbuf-from-homebrews-coreutils which tells you how to solve that problem.

Comment: @EdMorton Not sure I follow your suggested for-loop? If I redirect the output outside the for-loop (does that even work?), doesn't that miss the whole point with the original question - that I want the output while it happens? Currently the log is updated when each file is processed (I want it for every line/once a minute or so), with your suggestion, wouldn't it mean that the output would be written when ALL files are processed (which can take days). I don't think writing to file takes a lot of CPU, I/O or so. Typically one line of output is added every 20-30 seconds.

Comment: @EdMorton What do you mean by "and `for file in "$directory"` is confusing terminology at best or simply a bug, depending on what it's meant to do"? What is confusing or a bug?

Comment: @EdMorton For future reference, I actually had `stdbuf` but it is called `gstdbuf` in MacPorts. I knew this when I realised it (using `locate`), GNU ls is called gls, GNU cp gcp etc. Obvious in hindsight.

Comment: If you have a variable named `$directory` then it should contain the name of a directory, not a file, and so saying `for file in "$directory'` is confusing as `$directory` doesn't contain the name of a file.  Also `for anything in "$any_other_thing"` doesn't make sense as that loop will only iterate one time and that's with the value of `anything` set to exactly the value of `any_other_thing`. You may have either meant `for file in "$directory"/*` or `for file in "${directory[@]}"` or something else depending on how `directory` is populated, but `for file in "$directory"` is a bug.

Comment: @EdMorton That is exactly what it does. $directory points to a directory, and I then process all files in $directory [with some specific extensions].

Comment: That's not what `for file in "$directory"` does. Let's say you have a directory named `foo` and under that you have a file named `bar` that you want to process by calling `pythonscript "bar"` on it. In your code you would have `directory="foo"` followed by the code in your question, `for file in "$directory"; do pythonscript "$file"; done`. What that will NOT do is call `pythonscript "bar"` as desired, instead it will undesirably call `pythonscript "foo"`.

Comment: I just noticed [your other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77415449/force-flush-python-part-of-bash-script#comment136490959_77415449). No, when you write `for whatever; do stuff; done > file` the shell doesn't wait til the loop is done and THEN start writing to `file`, it sets `file` as the destination for stdout and empties `file` before the loop starts running, and then all stdout produced in the loop goes into `file` as it's produced, just like `> file; for whatever; do stuff >> file; done` would do but without the overhead of having to re-open the file on every loop iteration.

Comment: It's not a huge overhead but why introduce overhead unnecessarily and if you don't do it then it also mean you need to do `> file` to init `file` before the loop starts (so more/duplicate code) and if you want to run more commands in the loop you need to add `>> file` to the end of them too (even more duplicate code). Try running `( for i in {1..3}; do echo "$i"; sleep 2; done > file & ); tail -f file` and you'll see `file` being updated every time output is produced, not just when the loop finishes. You'll have to type control-C to end the `tail` once you're done looking at the loop output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` env var

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
for file in "$directory"; do
    pythonscript "$file" >> "log.txt"; then
done
```